# TYPO3: Custom Globals?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-7.x, typo3-8.7.x

I have some data (logins) I want to be ignored from git in my custom TYPO3 extension code.

As AdditionalConfiguration.php is already ignored in my case, it seems a good place to store such data.

It normally contains Data like

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['Connections']['Default']['dbname']
```

Now would it make sense to make something like custom globals? Does that exist?

```
$GLOBALS['CUSTOM_CONF_VARS']['MYEXT']['username']
```

Should and can I do that or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use your own globals. But I would consider using your own globals as bad programming style.
If you have installation specific data the right way to store the data depends on the kind of data and where you need it:

- everything for the Frondend should be stored in typoscript. This can be in a file from a site-extension or in the database (template record)
- for BE you could use Page- or User-TSconfig. here you also can use a file from a site-extension or database records (pages/be_user)
- if you have FE and BE or anything alse (e.g. scheduler jobs) you can use extension specific global data, you can set in the extension manager. -> [docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationOptions/Index.html).

Comment: Ok I understand. But what's the reason? Is it less performant if my (unversioned) variable is in /typo3conf/ instead or /typo3conf/ext/myext? Or just because of separation of concerns? EM Settings will also be in LocalConfiguration.php.

Comment: Ooops sorry I didn't read to the end! `extension specific global data` is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Bohoo... I moved all my settings to EM config with `ext_conf_template.txt` and then querying `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['myext']`. It works! BUT... the values are stored in `LocalConfiguration.php`, plaintext. Which enters into my git versioning. The problem is that I have an API password there. And I think it would be better practice not to version that. Is it somehow possible to either encrypt/decrypt that data or store it elsewhere (db or special file I can exclude from git)?

Comment: aside from LocalConfiguration.php you can use AdditionalConfiguration.php, where you can override any values from LocalConfiguration.php.

Comment: Yep. but there I have to write it manually, while if you set the settings in EM config, they will (probably?) always go to LocalConfiguration.php. I have now moved them to AdditionalConfiguration anyway.

Comment: maybe you can add the important values (those which needs to be versioned) to AdditionalConfiguration.php. leaving all individual, sensitive, ... data to LocalConfiguration.php (outside of versioning).

Comment: Oh! I'm having it exactly the other way round atm: Additional.. is excluded, individual & sensitive, while Local... is versioned (so you can sync extensions quickly via git between instances). I'll think about it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving `configuration` in `$GLOBALS` try use `typoscript`. Will be much easier to keep and maintain it.

Comment: While you may be right (I‘d just have to add the additionala TS file to gitignore), it doesnt answer my question if I can do it as described